# Why does this not return the conversion rate of each group but instead returns 100% for both SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I need to get the conversion rate of group A and Group B from the groups.group column.

This is the code I used;

```
SELECT
groups.group,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total_users,
COUNT(DISTINCT activity.uid) AS total_converted,
(COUNT(DISTINCT activity.uid)\*1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT id):: float \* 100) AS conversion_rate
FROM users
LEFT JOIN activity ON users.id = activity.uid
LEFT JOIN "groups" ON activity.uid = groups.uid
GROUP BY groups.group;
```

However it has the following output:
[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahGTp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query: -

```
SELECT
  groups.group,
  COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS total_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT activity.uid) AS total_converted,
  (COUNT(DISTINCT activity.uid)::float / COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) * 100) AS conversion_rate
FROM
  activity
LEFT JOIN "groups" ON activity.uid = groups.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = activity.uid
GROUP BY
  groups.group;
```